# How to unproject a point on screen to object space coordinates in vulkan?

Tags: projection, vulkan

I need to be able to unproject a screen pixel into object space using Vulkan, but somewhere my math is going wrong.

Here is the shader as it stands today for reference:

```c
void main()
{
    //the depth of this pixel is between 0 and 1
    vec4 obj_space = vec4( float(gl_FragCoord.x)/ubo.screen_width, float(gl_FragCoord.y)/ubo.screen_height, gl_FragCoord.z, 1.0f);
    //this puts us in normalized device coordinates [-1,1 ] range
    obj_space.xy = ( obj_space.xy * 2.0f ) -1.0f;

    //this two lines will put is in object space coordinates
    //mvp_inverse is derived from this in the c++ side: 
    //glm::inverse(app.three_d_camera->get_projection_matrix() * app.three_d_camera->view_matrix * model);

    obj_space = ubo.mvp_inverse * obj_space;
    obj_space.xyz /= obj_space.w;


    //the resulting position here is wrong
    out_color = obj_space;
}
```

when I output the position in color, the colors are off.  I know I can simply pass in the object space position from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, but I'd like to understand why my math is not working, it will help me understand Vulkan and maybe learn a little math myself.

Thanks!

Comment: the `box_space_pos` is supposed to be the `obj_space` variable, that is a typo.  Sorry guys, the question is still the same.

Comment: You can edit the question.

Comment: Math is fundamentally API-agnostic. Have you tried it in normal C code (which is more easily debugable)? Or (god forbid) on paper? Also have you tested the MVP matrix is sensible in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your problem is, but lets go over potential problems.

Remember, vulkan clip space is:

- positive y = **down**,
- positive x = right,
- positive z = out,
- centered at the middle of the screen.

Additionally, despite OpenGL's GLSL docs saying it is centered at the bottom left corner, in vulkan [gl_FragCoord is centered at the top left corner](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/d3dfb8262fb53a06dab64d065e16ed53e9c07e1c/extensions/khr/GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl.txt#L1050..L1065).

in this step:

```
obj_space.xy = ( obj_space.xy * 2.0f ) -1.0f;
```

obj_space is now:

- left x : -1.0
- right x : 1.0
- **top y = -1.0**
- **bottom y = 1.0**
- out z = 1.0
- back z = 0

I'm almost entirely sure you don't mean your object space to have Y be negative at the top.  The reasoning for y increasing starting from top to bottom is for images and textures, which on the CPU are ordered the same way, and now are ordered like that in vulkan.

Some other notes:

You claim your inverse is derivied from glm::inverse here:

```
glm::inverse(app.three_d_camera->get_projection_matrix() * app.three_d_camera->view_matrix * model);
```

But GLM uses OpenGL notation for matrix dimensions and handedness, and unless you force it to the correct coordinate system, it is going to assume right handed positive Y up, z negative out.  You'll need to include the following `#defines` before it works correctly (or physically change your calculations to accommodate this).

```
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#define GLM_FORCE_LEFT_HANDED
```

Additionally you'll need to modify your matrices to account for the negative Y direction. Here is an example of how I've handled this in the past (modifying the perspective matrix directly):

```
ubo.model = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(pos_x,pos_y,pos_z));
ubo.model *= glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), time * glm::radians(0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
ubo.view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
ubo.proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), swapChainExtent.width / (float) swapChainExtent.height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
ubo.proj[1][1] *= -1; // makes the y axis projected to the same as vulkans
```

Comment: "back z = -1.0". He does not modify z. Should probably be `0`. Also not sure how `y=-1` top would be a problem. If his original matrix is correct in the first place, it should account for any kind of world space he chooses, no?

Comment: @krOoze  We don't know if his original matrix is correct, if it was the -y thing wouldn't be a problem, I assumed that this person might not even know this is an issue that would need to be tackled at some point.

Comment: @krOoze  Also my intention was to show direction, not really bounds, but I can see how that is confusing, so I'll replace it with zero.

Comment: Sure, hence my question in comments. Although the worse that could happen is stuff would project upside down. But should unproject back to the original vector anyway.

Comment: @krOoze Remember, this person isn't even drawing objects on the screen, their "colors" are wrong, a inverted y axis could certainly cause "incorrect" colors.  I mean tbh, everything could be right, and they just didn't understand how to interpret their own color scheme, but at least some one thought this was a good question, so I've answered it to the best of my knowledge of their situation.

Comment: Sure, but it could be said the question violates MVCE, as Vulkan is superfluous (and unnecessarily complex) to the case of correctness of the used math. Hence I suggested to try outside Vulkan to eliminate unnecessary complications. BTW I think `inverse` calculation might not depend on handedness, and pretty certain it does not on depth range.

Comment: @krOoze I agree with your response to the original question, and I feel that is probably the best way to go about it.   I believe the `glm::perspective` handles implicit flipping of z for handedness,  but regardless when I assumed left handed z out, y up, it screwed my perspective up because GLM was doing *something* using an assumption of OpenGL's right handed system, I suspect this is the type of system OP is attempting to use as well (right = +x, up = +y, out = +z).

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments.  The problem ended up being related  to memory corruption when passing in the `inverse_mvp` matrix to the GPU, causing the colors I was seeing to look not as I was expecting.  So the shader I wrote is not wrong as long as you follow @opa's tips in his answer, which I did.  I will give him credit because his answer is very complete.   One final thing: for an explanation on how unprojection math works, go here:  https://www.derschmale.com/2014/09/28/unprojections-explained/